# Sharing data across devices - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, cloud

I'm developing an app for a term project (so forgive me if this is a moronic question) and I'm wondering how to save data for a user and share to a different device but same user. E.g. someone logs in on their phone logs their information how can it be pushed to their tablet?  I'm leaning towards just making it an android only app and using kotlin & android studio however, if someone knows of a solution in a different language and/or using a framework like flutter I'm open to it.

Comment: You will need some sort of server, whether using a Web service that you create or using some "off the shelf" solution (e.g., Firebase's storage options).

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that. Would you recommend firebase?